# flutter phone auth doens't work in my boss phone

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

helllo

I'm trying to make phone auth with flutter
I managed to implement but doens't work in my boss phone (android)
in my phone it works.
that's why I'm almost crazy

I wanna connect boss phone with cable debug mode
but my boss refused to it.

here's my code

```
Future createUserWithPhone({String phoneNumber, BuildContext context}) async {
    String phoneNumberWith82 = '+82 $phoneNumber';

    await fAuth.verifyPhoneNumber(
        phoneNumber: phoneNumberWith82,
        timeout: Duration(seconds: 60),
        verificationCompleted: (AuthCredential authCredential) async {
          print('here verificationcompleted');
✅ not a big deal, verificationCompleted doesn't work don't know why
          await fAuth
              .signInWithCredential(authCredential)
              .then((AuthResult result) {
            Fluttertoast.showToast(
              msg: "success",
              backgroundColor: Colors.black26,
              textColor: Colors.white,
            );
          }).catchError((e) {
            print('Error Occurs ⭐3');
            return "error";
          });
        },
        verificationFailed: (AuthException exception) {
          Fluttertoast.showToast(
              msg: 'too many request',
              toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_LONG,
              gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM,
              timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
              backgroundColor: Colors.red,
              textColor: Colors.white,
              fontSize: 16.0);
          return "error";
        },
        codeSent: (String verificationId, [int forceResendingToken]) async {
          final _codeController = TextEditingController();
          await showDialog(
            context: context,
            barrierDismissible: false,
            builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
              title: Text("write auth 6digit"),
              content: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: <Widget>[
                  TextField(
                    controller: _codeController,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              actions: <Widget>[
                FlatButton(
                  child: Text("verify"),
                  textColor: Constants.kPrimaryOrange,
                  // color: Constants.kPrimaryOrange,
                  onPressed: () async {

                    var _credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(
                        verificationId: verificationId,
                        smsCode: _codeController.text.trim());

✅ Error Occurs HERE ✅✅✅✅✅✅✅✅✅✅✅✅✅✅✅✅✅✅✅✅
                    await fAuth
                        .signInWithCredential(_credential)
                        .then((AuthResult result) async {
                     
                      var snapshot = await Firestore.instance
                          .collection('users')
                          .where('pid', isEqualTo: result.user.phoneNumber)
                          .getDocuments();

                      /// id doesn't exist.
                      if (snapshot.documents.length == 0) {
                        
                        await Firestore.instance
                            .collection('users')
                            .document(result.user.uid)
                            .setData({
                          'uid': result.user.uid,
                          'pid': result.user.phoneNumber,
                          'name': randomName,
                          'createdAt': DateTime.now(),
                          'storeName': '',                         
                        });
                        Fluttertoast.showToast(
                          msg: "33",
                          backgroundColor: Colors.black26,
                          textColor: Colors.white,
                        );
                        
                      } else {
                        Fluttertoast.showToast(
                          msg: " id exists",
                          backgroundColor: Colors.black26,
                          textColor: Colors.white,
                        );
                      
                      }
                      setUser(result.user);
                      
                      Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
                          context, SplashScreen.id, (route) => false,
                          arguments: result.user);
              
✅ catch               }).catchError((e) {
                      Fluttertoast.showToast(                         
                          msg: e.toString(),
                          toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_LONG,
                          gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM,
                          timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
                          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                          textColor: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 16.0);
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) =>
                                ErrorReading(errorMsg: e.toString())),
                      );
                      // Navigator.pop(context);

                      return "error";
                    });
                  },
                ),
                FlatButton(
                  child: Text("close"),
                  textColor: Constants.kPrimaryOrange,
                  // color: Constants.kPrimaryOrange,
                  onPressed: () {
                    print('Error Occurs ⭐');
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  },
                )
              ],
            ),
          );
        },
        codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (String verificationId) {
          verificationId = verificationId;
        });
```

I don't know cause of this problem , so i cannot fix it.
I used to toast to find error point.
then i found it ✅ look at this emoji

anybody?

```
  firebase_auth: ^0.16.1
  firebase_core: ^0.4.0
  cloud_firestore: ^0.13.0
  firebase_storage: ^3.1.6
```

I tryed firebase_auth ^18 with core ^5 but many place to change recent code so I trying to figuring out with these versions

Comment: Have you added your Android Studio's SHA-1 fingerprint in "Project Overview > Project Settings > Your apps > Your Android app > SHA certificate fingerprints"? I know that Firebase phone verification needs your app's SHA-1 fingerprint for it to work (in debug and release).

Comment: Moreover you need to activate the Device Check API in GCP. Have you tried that?
Have a look at these [steps](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth)

Comment: thanks for your replies ,
#Martin : yes I did 
#Ayush Surana : I didn't activate Device Check API , So I activate and wait my boss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the steps as mentioned [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth).

You need to add both the SHA-1 Fingerprint and enable the Device Check API for Phone Auth to work in Android.

If you need a code sample for Phone Auth to work in
firebase_auth ^18 with core ^5, do let me know will edit this answer.

Comment: I activated Device Check API and now I can receive Error msg 
before activation , I cannot even get the error msg.
good good 
it was expired error. it's new phase 

and (I can search about firebaseauth ^18with core ^5) = (I don't wanna bothering you )
thanks though 